# Euclidean distance of inputs under a Laplace Kernel

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a function $\phi : \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow Q$ such that
    our kernel
    $K(x_i,x_j) = \phi(x_i) \cdot \phi(x_j) =
\exp(-\frac{1}{2}\|x_i-x_j\|).$
    As we can see, this is often referred to as the Laplace Kernel. I want
    to prove that for any two inputs $x_i$ and $x_j$, their Euclidean
    distance between their corresponding points in $Q$ is at most $2$.
    We can see that

$$\|\phi(x_i) - \phi(x_j)\|^2 =
(\phi(x_i)-\phi(x_j)) \cdot (\phi(x_i) - \phi(x_j))^T$$
    $$= <\phi(x_i),\phi(x_i)> + <\phi(x_j),\phi(x_j)>
- 2<\phi(x_i),\phi(x_j)>.$$

However, I am now having issues manipulating this calculation into
    results that look reasonably similar to the Laplace kernel function we
    have initialized. Any recommendations?

Comment: ? $\langle \phi(x_i),\phi(x_j) \rangle \overset{def}= K(x_i,x_j)$

Comment: It seems very coarse, but a simple application of the triangle inequality works here.